# How to add site Validation for all pages

Tags: google-search-console

I want to implement google site validate meta tag on each page page of my site. I tried Site_validation module but its allows to implement the google meta tags only on front page.
Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do that is using the "site_verify" module and you can add another hook to add it to all page that will look like this:
 `/**
 * Implements hook_init().
 *
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_init() {
  $meta_tags = db_query("SELECT svid, meta FROM {site_verify} WHERE meta <> ''")->fetchAllKeyed();
  foreach ($meta_tags as $svid => $meta_tag) {
    $data = array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => $meta_tag . "\n",
    );
    drupal_add_html_head($data, 'site_verify:' . $svid);
  }
}`

you need to change "YOUR_MODULE" with your custom module name. Also clear drupal cach after adding it